How to handle modal dialog in Selenium WebDriver Java?
I came across such a modal dialog, the interaction with which is not solved in the usual way.
<div class="overlay-container is-active" id="js-XFUniqueId528">
    <div class="overlay" tabindex="-1" data-url="https://www..." role="dialog" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="overlay-title">Title</div>
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <form action="/.../bump" method="post" class="block" data-xf-init="ajax-submit"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="_xfToken" value="45634566,67f2bff8c3127d2579e2a3d60bff8c31271">
                <div class="block-container">
                    <div class="block-body">...</div>
                    <dl class="formRow formSubmitRow"> <dt></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <div class="formSubmitRow-main">
                                <div class="formSubmitRow-bar"></div>
                                <div class="formSubmitRow-controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--lock">
                        <span class="button-text">Raise</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I tried to use this to click on the dialog button, but it doesn't solve the problem:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement modal = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("js-XFUniqueId528")));
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button--primary"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", submitButton);
submitButton.click();

and the following
Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> I1 = s.iterator();
driver.switchTo().window(I1.next());
WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button--primary"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", submitButton);
submitButton.click();

The result was just ElementNotInteractableException:
Element <button class="button--primary button button--icon
button--icon--search" type="submit"> could not be scrolled into view

What is the correct way to press a button in such a modal dialog?

you don't need any of the switchto or handle stuff.  That's for switching context to a different tab/window/frame.  From what you posted, this is just a  in the current context.  Use webdriverwait with expected condition of toBeClickable... target the button.  Confirm that this is the only button with button--primary class.  There could be one in the background of the modal as well.... if there's another you probably need a partly path-based locator to target the right one.  (child of your modal element you got by id)
